# How do I declare an iterator for a map with the following template - std::map<std::string, T> my_map?

Tags: c++, templates, iterator, stdmap

I have the following class declaration -

```
template <typename T> 
class Polynomial{
  std::map<std::string, T> _polynomial_
}
```

In a member function I declared an iterator for this -

```
typename std::map<std::string, T>::iterator it= _polynomial_.begin();
```

The completed member function looks like this -

```
template <typename T>
void Polynomial<T>::print(std::ostream& out) const
{


  typename std::map<std::string, T>::iterator it= _polynomial_.begin();
  std::string term;
  while(it != _polynomial_.end()){


    term = it->second;
    term += it->first;
    if(it->first < (T)0){
      out << "-" << term;
    }
    else{
      out << "+" << term;
    }
    term = "";
    it++;
  }


}
```

In main, I call the function as follows -

```
 Polynomial <double> p1;

  p1.add_term("x0",9.862);

  std::cout << p1;
```

However this does not seem to work and I get errors. GCC complains of a 
conversion error -

Polynomial.hpp:32:47: error: conversion from \u2018std::map, double, std::less >, std::allocator, double> > >::const_iterator {aka std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator, double> >}\u2019 to non-scalar type \u2018std::map, double, std::less >, std::allocator, double> > >::iterator {aka std::_Rb_tree_iterator, double> >}\u2019 requested
   typename std::map::iterator it= *polynomial*.begin();

Can someone tell me what is the correct declaration of the iterator?

Comment: Could you elaborate? It looks fine to me.

Comment: Read the errors.  If the errors don't make sense to you, add the errors to your question.  Alternatively provide a minimal complete program demonstrating the issue.

Comment: I have added more details. Any help much appreciated...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Polynomial<T>::print` is a `const` member function, inside which the data member `_polynomial_` becomes `const` too, that means what `_polynomial_.begin()` returns is a `const_iterator`, which can't be converted to `iterator` implicitly. (Note that [`std::map::begin`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/begin) is overloaded with `const` version and non-`const` version, the former returns `const_iterator` and the latter returns `iterator`.)

Change the code to

```
typename std::map<std::string, T>::const_iterator it = _polynomial_.begin();
//                                 ^^^^^^
```

or use [`auto`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto) instead, it would deduce the correct type for you.

```
auto it = _polynomial_.begin();
```

Comment: Thanks songyuanyao! That seems to have resolved the issue with the conversion error!